# Ruby Prime number program

Tags: ruby, math

I know similar questions have been asked before but they all seem so over complicated and I don't think i'm that far off, so was wondering if anyone knows how to tweak my code to get it to work. My goal is to save all prime numbers of a range into an array and then print that array. Below is my code so far

```
prime_array = []

(1...100).each do |num|
  if Math.sqrt(num) % 2 == 0
    prime_array.push(num)
  end
end

prime_array
#=> [4, 16, 36, 64]
```

I've tried a few different options but have hit a wall and can't see what i need to do. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible as I feel a lot of the answers out there a little over complicated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Come on, you can do this yourself.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `Class#Prime` library?

Comment: Haha @meier I've tried I promise! I just can't work out how to isolate the prime numbers!

Comment: @philip_yoo no I was hoping to find a solution without it

Comment: Than just check is a number is not a prime number.

Comment: Brute force it, use 2 loops to find all divisors of the current number. If the number is divisible by only 2 numbers (itself and by 1), then its a prime. Also, the initial few numbers you will probably just need to add yourself (i.e. 1, 2, 3..)

Comment: The result of your code is `[4, 16, 36, 64]` i.e. the squares of even numbers. This is quite different from finding prime numbers. I think it may be more productive for you to ask about the parts of the "over complicated" solutions that you have found that you do not understand (or perhaps you could ask why a part that seems not necessary to you is needed by an example you have found). Otherwise it is very likely someone will show you a variation of the "over complicated" code here, and that won't help.

Comment: come on, don't cheat, RuNpiXelruN should get the satisfaction to solve this problem alone. It was my first program on a programmable calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's calculate the square root of 7 (a prime number) and 8 (a composite number):

```
Math.sqrt(7) #=> 2.6457513110645907
Math.sqrt(8) #=> 2.8284271247461903
```

This doesn't really help, does it? Apparently, you can't determine if a number is a prime number by calculating its square root.

Instead, you have to check the number's divisors. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number):

> A **prime number** (or a **prime**) is a [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) greater than 1 that has no positive [divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) other than 1 and itself.

Let's determine the divisors of 7: (using the modulo operator [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-25))

```
7 % 1 #=> 0 <- 7 is divisible by 1
7 % 2 #=> 1
7 % 3 #=> 1
7 % 4 #=> 3
7 % 5 #=> 2
7 % 6 #=> 1
7 % 7 #=> 0 <- 7 is divisible by 7
```

This satisfies the above definition - 7 is a prime number.

Now, let's determine the divisors of 8:

```
8 % 1 #=> 0 <- 8 is divisible by 1
8 % 2 #=> 0 <- 8 is divisible by 2
8 % 3 #=> 2
8 % 4 #=> 0 <- 8 is divisible by 4
8 % 5 #=> 3
8 % 6 #=> 2
8 % 7 #=> 1
8 % 8 #=> 0 <- 8 is divisible by 8
```

8 has two additional divisors 2 and 4. Therefore, 8 is *not* a prime number.

In Ruby, you could use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to find the divisors:

```
(1..7).select { |d| 7 % d == 0 } #=> [1, 7]
(1..8).select { |d| 8 % d == 0 } #=> [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Finally, here's a variant of your Ruby code that checks if a given number `num` has exactly two divisors, `1` and `num` itself:

```
prime_array = []

(1...100).each do |num|
  if (1..num).select { |d| num % d == 0 } == [1, num]
    prime_array.push(num)
  end
end

prime_array
#=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

The above code can be optimized. I leave that to you.

Comment: thankyou so much. Such a great answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Method that returns prime numbers in an array in ruby

```
 def is_prime?(number)
       return false if number <2
        (2..Integer.sqrt(number)).each do |divisor|
              return false if number % divisor == 0
  end
     return number
end

def read_array(array)
     primes = []
  array.each do |num|
       primes << num if is_prime?(num)
  end
 return primes
end
```